# jquery owl-carousel owl-dots class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, owl-carousel

I get some problem when I use owl-carousel in my Rails project.
when I go back to the cached page of my browsers which is using carousel class, I get too many carousel owl-dot classes in my page,this is my

JS code

```
function initScrollboxHobby() {
    var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
    owl.owlCarousel({
        // loop: true,
        items: 1,
        nav: true
    });
}
```

and issue HTML code

[image]

How to fix it ?

Comment: Hey! Try to log something in `initScrollboxHobby`, as it looks it was initialized multiple times.

Comment: I suppose it's a bug maybe.. only in owl-carousel-rails, or I used it in wrong way?..I removed all the owl-dots and owl-nav classes by jquery code before every time I initialized owl-carousel function, and for could looping items, also removed those items which with cloned class. x_x

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using turboinks and when you go back the page is cached by it and when it loads it reruns the owl carousel init function.

The problem, básically, is that turbolinks doesn't play well with non-idempotent functions https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent

I've managed to make a workaround for this problem with other js plugins, so it should work for you.

Básically, the idea is:

First, when the user enters the page for the first time, copy the content of the element with class `.owl-carousel` on itself as a data attribute

```
carousel = $('.owl-carousel');
carousel.data('originalHtml', carousel.html();
carousel.owlCarousel(....)
```

Then, when the users goes back, before initializing the carousel, check if it was initialized and cached, in that case, first replace the content with the original and remove classes

```
carousel = $('.owl-carousel');
if (carousel.hasClass('owl-loaded')) {
  carousel.html(carousel.data('originalHTML')).removeClass('owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag');
}
carousel.owlCarousel(....)
```

You can mix both steps into one:

```
$(function() {
  const carousel = $('.owl-carousel');
  if (carousel.hasClass('owl-loaded')) { //if it has the class then it means it's the cached view
    carousel.html(carousel.data('originalHTML')).removeClass('owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag');
  } else { // else it's a fresh load of the page
    carousel.data('originalHtml', carousel.html());
  }
  carousel.owlCarousel(....)
})
```

It's a little bit hacky, but the only way I found to use plugins that are not prepared to work with turbolinks without going through modifying those plugins.

Another option would be to just disable Turbolinks if you thing you just don't need it.

Comment: A specific reason, but I can't removed the necessary classes which are already written in the static page, I only removed the issue classes.

Answer (score 0):

For arieljuod's help of problem reason and my own trying.

I  coded like this now.

```
var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
var owl_navs = $('.owl-carousel .owl-nav');
var owl_dots = $('.owl-carousel .owl-dots');
var owl_cloned = $('.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer .owl-stage .cloned');

if(owl.hasClass('owl-loaded'))
{
    owl_navs.remove();
    owl_dots.remove();
    owl_cloned.remove();
}
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
    nav: true
});
```

It's tedious but worked well.

Now,I understanded reason.

When I go back to cached page,because I wrote javascript code in my ERB file,in that way, old HTML code may changed.

And then Turbolinks function will run the JS code in that CHANGED new HTML code,Turbolinks must do that,because when I visit cached page again,it will lose all the event binds.

So the whole carousel items will be messy.

Comment: The problem is NOT that you have used javascript on your erb file, the problem is that turbolinks expects all transformations to be idempotent.

Comment: Yes I know, actually I means because of turbolinks's defect ,the JS code in body element may get the issues only in Rails, it's not the reason ,but it can cause the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry to insist on my corrections, but your comment may mislead people reading them. It's not a `defect` of turbolinks, it's made that way by design even documented (and it makes sense). The JS could be on the body, on the head, anywhere, if it's not idempotent it can cause the same thing. I doesn't affect only Rails projects, turbolinks is a frontend plugin, it can be used with any backend language since it does not depend on it. Finally, it's not a defect nor an issue, it's just a condition if you want to use Turbolinks on any project.

Comment: Ok,thanks to your comments,this time I entirely understand.It is not a bug,more like a design feature?I will revise my word.It's my fault,and I supposed turbolinks only use in rails project before.